# Ubuntu Software is not working at all in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center, 20.04

I got an fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04, but Software Center can't find any application when asked and instead only shows a grey background in the app. I tried to install some software using the console and everything was fine, so I suppose that it is a serious bug in Software Center.

My PC hardware is configurated as follows:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- 16GB of Ram DDR4 at 3000MHz
- Motherboard: GIGABYTE B450-DS3H
- Generic SSD for storage.